# Creating weighted sum analysis using DEM and population data using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, weighted-overlay

I have a shapefile containing population points for Vietnam, and I am aiming to perform a weighted sum analysis using a Digital Elevation Model. 
Basically, I'd like to combine elevation, population densities and slope to find the best areas for terraced cultivation. I have a full DEM for Vietnam, and population densities.

The ideal locations would be medium slope angles without high population densities. 
However I'm a bit stuck on what path to follow.

Comment: My question is: is there a way I can perform a slope analysis using the DEM, and combine slope with population data inside a weighted sum analysis to find suitable areas. I need a slope between 10° and 15. My issue is that I don't really see how I can weigh the slope.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications. The question you wish to ask will be obvious when it has a question mark at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an outline of a basic method.

1. **Filter each of your layers based on your conditions.**

   *Slope*

   i. [Create a slope raster from the DEM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218272/creating-slope-map-from-dem-using-qgis/218273).

   ii. Use the Raster calculator to create a raster with values of 1 when slope is acceptable (between 10 and 15 degrees), and 0 when the slope is unacceptable.

   ```
   @rasterband * (@rasterband > 10 AND @rasterband < 15)
   ```

   *Population*

   i. Convert your subjective condition (high/low population density) to an objective range of numerical values. Define what an acceptable range of population density would be.

   ii. Create a raster with values of 1 when population density is acceptable , and 0 when the population density is unacceptable.

   *Elevation*

   i. Define a range of acceptable elevations.

   ii. Use the Raster calculator to create a raster with values of 1 when elevation is acceptable, and 0 when the elevation is unacceptable.
2. **Find the area where the filtered layers overlap.**

   [Use the `r.series` tool to sum the three rasters together](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182462/summing-pixel-values-from-several-raster-layers-with-partial-overlap-in-qgis).

The output is a raster with values between 0 and 3. Any cell with a value of 3 meets all 3 of your criteria.

Note that this method can be modified to create a more nuanced output. Instead of making rasters with only 0 or 1, you can use a range of values between 0 and 1, such that 0 means a cell doesn't meet conditions at all, and 1 means the cell has optimal conditions. It's up to you to decide what you define as "optimal" for each condition.